# Complexity class for loop with two inner loops

Tags: complexity-theory

I have an algorithm like the following

```
for(int k) {
    statement1;
    for(int j) {
        statement2;
    }
    for(int m) {
        statement3;
    }
 }
```

j => m

Is it correct for me to conclude that the complexity class is O(n^2)?

Comment: Sure it looks like O(k * max(j, m)) = O(k * j) using the constraint, but this pseudo-code doesn't give much information.

Comment: You'll have to edit the question to tell us what the range of `k`, `j`, and `m` are.  The answer will depend on the answer to that.  Anyway, it looks like this is covered by [our reference material](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/599/755).